# Button url caching Dynamics CRM 4 issue

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have added a custom button, with url + javascript by chaning the isv xml file, as described on

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc150860.aspx

and all works fine.  However, when I try and replace the file in the /ISV/ folder, it behaves the same as the original copy, I assume this is caching related.  However, if I access the file from outside the CRM that is http://server/ISV/file.htm it has the latest and correct version.  How do I get around this caching issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So your ISV Option points to "/ISV/file.htm"?  I think in the past I've noticed CRM's IIS site caching static files for 3 days.  What I would do is when you replace your file.htm in your ISV folder, also update the ISV.config:

So change it to point to "/ISV/file.htm?vers=00001" and then increment each time you update the file.